# Android: textwatcher

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема.
Дописываю в onCreate код для textWathera:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    TextView interval1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    interval1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
}
```

Запускаю приложение и оно сразу же крашится
Лог:

```
03-16 12:36:00.260: D/AndroidRuntime(1172): Shutting down VM
03-16 12:36:00.260: W/dalvikvm(1172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-16 12:36:00.270: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Покажите 31 строку из MainActivity

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

Comment: Покажите ещё `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

Comment: Ну так в `activity_main.xml` у вас отсутствует `R.id.editText1`, потому после выполнения

    TextView interval1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

переменная `interval1` равна `null`, и, как следствие, `NullPointerException`, который вы и получаете.

Comment: она есть во fragment_main.xml
    <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
   android:ems="10" >

Comment: В таком случае, в `PlaceholderFragment` вам и стоит с ним работать, например, в `onViewCreated`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вроде работает) столько времени убил на поиск решения и оказывается даже рядом не был)